# remove *.debug.js from master page 

Tags: publishing-site, master-page

When I view my SharePoint site I see a lot of .debug.js files being added by SharePoint.  Is there a way to stop this happening.

1. cui.debug.js
2. core.debug.js
3. sp.debug.js
4. sp.ribbon.debug.js
5. init.debug.js

they account for around 400k of the page download.

The format map is also accounting for a fair chunk of the page weight.

I know how to use the security trimmed control but I dont know where these items are and what is safe to wrap with the control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'oh! turns out setting the `debug="false"` value in the `system.web` section removes the .debug.js files from the client download...

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false" optimizeCompilations="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can debug the code through Firebug(firefox) or debugbar(IE) the and you will see all process are necesary.

try it ;)